# Use custom font for numbers in linguex examples

Tags: fonts, linguistics, examples, linguex

I have a custom font specifically for numbered lists -- it renders the numbers in an enumeration in a nicer way than the standard main font. Once I've loaded the font into a new font family which I call `\numfont` (using `fontspec`), I can use it in enumeration like so:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item[{\numfont 1}] his
    \item[{\numfont 2}] her
\end{enumerate}
```

Is there a way to do something similar for the numbers in a `linguex` example? I would prefer something similar in style to how I did it above, rather than changing the font for the numbers universally. The font I have only draws numbers (not alphabets), so I would prefer to use it only in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to patch into the left and right bracket code of the example formatting. I've used `\sffamily` here in place of your `\numfont` which you don't define.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\renewcommand{\ExLBr}{(\sffamily} % using \sffamily as an example
\renewcommand{\ExRBr}{\normalfont)}
\begin{document}

\ex. This is an example

\ex.
\a. This is a subexample.
\b. This is 

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]